# why my function insert is looping the last data?

Tags: php, pdo

This is my class Sql.php extending from PDO.

```
private $conn;
    
function __Construct(){
    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7","root","root");
}

private function setParams($comando,$params){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($comando);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam($key,$value);
    }
    echo $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}

private function comando($comando,$params = array()){
    $this->setParams($comando,$params);
}

public function select($comando,$params = []): array{
    $stmt = $this->setParams($comando,$params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function insert($comando,$params = array()){
    $this->comando($comando,$params);
    return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
}
```

And This is my index.php.

```
$obj = new Sql();
$obj->insert("INSERT INTO tb_usuarios(deslogin,dessenha) VALUES (?,?)",[
    1=>'marcos',
    2=>'123']
);
```

I want to know why the last value is looping. Anybody please help me 
[sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZq9m.png)

Comment: Oh, this is probably because you have used  `bindParam()` instead of `bindValue()`. `bindParam()` binds by reference, so the variable `$value` ends with 123 and modifies all references. Use `bindValue()` instead.

Comment: Thank you i'll try it